# Variable height CollectionView inside a self-sized TableView cell with AutoLayout on iOS8+

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uicollectionview

I have a `UITableView` with self-sized cell's height using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and AutoLayout constraints. On one of prototype cells I need to add `UICollectionView` with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` which will layout cells vertically in a single column for Compact Size Classes or in grid of 3 columns for Regular Size Classes. The height of the collection view is therefore dynamic and the layout may change even on rotation on iPhone 6 Plus (Compact->Regular).

I setup my tableview with custom prototype cells in storyboard and add the custom collectionview into a prototype cell, AutoLayout constraints always to zero to the corresponding edge of the superview (leading, trailing, top, bottom = 0 to superview) ... collectionView->tableviewContentView->tableviewCell.

I need the variable height of the collection view to drive the height of the tableview prototype cell. So far I am always getting the following AutoLayout error on runtime.

```
Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.
```

Can you please suggest the right approach to this? Thank you!

**Main TableViewController:**

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200.0
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
    /// ... plus tableview datasource functions
}
```

**CollectionView:**

```
class AttachmentCollectionView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        let nib = UINib(nibName: Constants.AttachmentCollectionView.cellNibName, bundle: nil)
        registerNib(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Constants.AttachmentCollectionView.cellIdentifier)
        collectionViewLayout = attachmentFlowLayout()
        dataSource = self
        delegate = self
        backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

    private func attachmentFlowLayout() -> UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .Vertical
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 70, height: 50)
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0
        layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0)
        layout.footerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0)
        return layout
    }
    // ...plus collectionview datasource functions
}
```

Comment: If have you finished it then can you send me a demo code for it , i have 5 section in table view , and in the last section one row there is a collection view,without scrollable , i want its dynamic size with dynamic table cell size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think implementing the tableView's delegate method `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat` may work.

Comment: It may work, but that's the pre iOS8 approach to self-sized tableview cells. I am looking for a way how the content of the collectiveview will drive the height of the tableview cell automatically with autolayout, if it's even possible.

Comment: @MartinKoles: After reading http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift, I'm guessing your issue may be the constraints you've placed on your CollectionView. My guess is that the CollectionView doesn't have a height constraint, which then doesn't allow the tableViewCell to determine the size of it's content.

Comment: Thanks, but after a quick review I don't see the reading involve any dynamic content on scrollview subclass like tableview or collectionview. I do have a vertical constraints for the collection view, but as it is a subclass of scrollview, the constraints just positions the collection view itself and tells nothing about its content to the autolayout engine. I am guessing now if my simple use of FlowLayout even defines the contentSize of the collectionview. Should not I do a proper subclass of UICollectionViewLayout and calculate the contentSize there?

Comment: @MartinKoles: What do you mean you have vertical constraints on the collection view? You have the top and bottom pinned? Because I think, like you said, that doesn't tell anything about the size of the contents. You'll probably need to provide an explicit height constraint for the collection view.

Comment: Yes, I have the top and the bottom of the collectionview pinned, but that's apparently not enough. I'll try to make a function to calculate the height of the collectionview based on a SizeClass and provide the height to the FlowLayout for content size, to the collectionview for the height constraint and if that's not enough I will provide it to the cell in the delegate method you suggested. I just thought there is a better way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hi Martin. Were you able to find a solution to this? I have been stuck on this issue for two days straight.